# C# WP8 Copy File SD Card, Access denied

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, file-copying, storagefile

I try copy file from D:\Data\ to D:\WPSystem\APPS{GUID}\Install\ and i have error Access denied, who can help me and/or rebuild source ?

Pocket file manager can add new files without any errors

Anyone ever mentioned "However to copy files to apps folder try to use StorageFolder and StorageFile classes"

But I do not know how to apply it

Source : [Click](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=607B3CC3588F4929!1940&authkey=!AH9m3kNPQaKVjUw&ithint=file%2Crar)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using PhoneApp1.Resources;
using System.IO;

namespace PhoneApp1

{

    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var directory = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\WPSystem\\") { Attributes = System.IO.FileAttributes.Normal };
                directory.Attributes = System.IO.FileAttributes.Normal;
                foreach (var info in directory.GetFileSystemInfos("*"))
                {
                    info.Attributes = System.IO.FileAttributes.Archive;
                }

                var dir = directory.GetDirectories("apps").FirstOrDefault();
                if (dir != null)
                {

                    dir.MoveTo("D:\\WPSystem\\appsx");

                    var dir2 = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\WPSystem\appsx\{GUID}\Install\");

                    var file = dir2.GetFiles("AppManifest.xaml").FirstOrDefault();

                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        file.Delete();
                    }

                    Directory.Move("D:\\WPSystem\\appsx", "D:\\WPSystem\\apps");

                    var data = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\Data\\");

                    var appmanifest = data.GetFiles("AppManifest.xaml").FirstOrDefault();

                    if (appmanifest != null)
                    {
                        appmanifest.CopyTo(
                            "D:\\WPSystem\\apps\\{GUID}\\Install\\File.bin");
                    }
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Success !");
                //Application.Current.Terminate();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error"+ Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pocket file manager can add new files without any errors Anyone ever mentioned "However to copy files to apps folder try to use StorageFolder and StorageFile classes" But I do not know how to apply it

Answer (score 0):

if you're getting an Access Denied exception problem is not in the code. Either the user running the application does not have privileges to run this, or the file/destination folder is locked for some reason.